# Difference between shallowReadonly and computed with reactive object (Vue)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

I’m using composable functions for a state management in my Vue 3 app (inspiration from [article on vueschool.io](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/state-management-with-composition-api/)).

I am consuming a certain composable function (in this case `useAssets`) in another files. I want to make sure, that I am able to directly change the property (variable) value only from the composable function itself. To enforce this immutability, I can use either `computed`, `readonly` or `shallowReadonly`, like this:

```ts
// useAssets
const erc20Tokens = ref<AssetERC20[]>([])
const erc721Tokens = ref<AssetERC721[]>([])
const erc1155Tokens = ref<AssetERC1155[]>([])

export default function useAssets() {
  return {
    erc20Tokens: computed(() => erc20Tokens.value),
    erc721Tokens: readonly(erc721Tokens),
    erc1155Tokens: shallowReadonly(erc721Tokens)
  }
}
```

I did my own little research and I found out a difference between `readonly` and `computed` when using with reactive object - mutating nested properties is not possible when using `readonly`. But I am not sure, what are the differences between `shallowReadonly` and `computed` in this case. I'm using the `useAssets` composable like this in another file (where I do not want to be possible to mutate the tokens variables from the useAssets composable)

```ts
// erc20Tokens: computed(() => erc20Tokens.value)
const { erc20Tokens: usingComputed } = useAssets()
usingComputed.value = null // TS2540: Cannot assign to 'value' because it is a read-only property
usingComputed.value[0] = null
usingComputed.value[0].name = null

// erc721Tokens: readonly(erc721Tokens), where erc721Tokens is reactive object
let { erc721Tokens: usingReadonly } = useAssets()
usingReadonly.value = null // TS2540: Cannot assign to 'value' because it is a read-only property.
usingReadonly.value[0] = null // TS2542: Index signature in type 'readonly { readonly token....} only permits reading
usingReadonly.value[0].name = null // TS2540: Cannot assign to 'name' because it is a read-only property.

// so the difference between readonly and computed is, that usingReadonly sets all nested properties to readonly too

// Regarding reassigning the variable itself (usingComputed = null) 
// depends only on what did you used for variable declaration (const vs let).
// If const, it will throw you an error, if let then it will pass. Both for computed and readonly.
usingReadonly = null // declared above with let
usingComputed = null // declared above with const | TS2588: Cannot assign to 'usingComputed' because it is a constant.

// But I have no idea what is then the difference between shallowReadonly and computed 
// when using reactive object :D

// erc1155Tokens: shallowReadonly(erc1155Tokens)
const { erc1155Tokens: usingShallowReadonly } = useAssets()
usingShallowReadonly.value = null // TS2540: Cannot assign to 'value' because it is a read-only property.
usingShallowReadonly.value[0] = null
usingShallowReadonly.value[0].name = null // does not throw, behave the same as usingComputed
```

I understand that `shallowReadonly` and `computed` accepts different parameters, etc., but I am wondering what are the differences when using these **with reactive object**? Thank you for your answers! Have a nice day:)

Comment: In this specific case there may be no difference, but only because you provide a a ref as an input and expect read-only ref as an output. Generally the difference is that computed always returns a ref with customizable setter, and `reactive`, etc return an object of the same structure.

Comment: Yes, so with reactive objects, there is no difference between `shallowReadonly` and `computed`, right? At least from practical point of view...